# I have some trouble with the function glColor3fv

Tags: python, opengl, colors, pygame

I'm making some graphics with OpenGL but i have some problems with the function glColor3fv.

I've made a cube with edges and faces... and now i want to put colors on the faces.

i've made this in code

```
vertices = (
(0, 0, 0), #point 0
(1, 0, 0), #point 1
(0, 1, 0), #point 2
(1, 1, 0), #point 3
(0, 0, 1), #point 4
(1, 0, 1), #point 5
(0, 1, 1), #point 6
(1, 1, 1)  #point 7
)

edges = (
(0,1),  # arrete entre le point 0 et 1
(0,4),  # arrete entre le point 0 et 4
(1,3),  # arrete entre le point 1 et 3
(1,5),  # arrete entre le point 1 et 5
(3,2),  # arrete entre le point 3 et 2
(3,7),  # arrete entre le point 3 et 7
(2,0),  # arrete entre le point 2 et 0
(2,6),  # arrete entre le point 2 et 6
(4,5),  # arrete entre le point 4 et 5
(5,7),  # arrete entre le point 5 et 7
(7,6),  # arrete entre le point 7 et 6
(6,4)   # arrete entre le point 6 et 4
)

surfaces = (
(0,1,3,2),  # Face du bas
(0,1,5,4),  # Face de devant
(0,4,6,2),  # Face de gauche
(7,6,4,5),  # Face du haut 
(7,3,1,5),  # Face de droite
(7,6,2,3)  # Face de derrière

)
colors=(
(1.000,0.920,0.000), #Jaune
(0.000,0.860,0.000), #Vert
(1.000,0.480,0.000), #Orange
(1.000,1.000,1.000), #Blanc
(0.900,0.000,0.000), #Rouge
(0.000,0.000,0.950) #Bleu
)

def Cube():
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    for surface in surfaces:
        for vertex in surface:
            glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])
            glColor3fv(colors[surface])
    glEnd()

    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for edge in edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])
   glEnd()
```

After i show the cube with pygame but the problem is that the function glColor3fv don't like the tuples in the list colors:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: The error tells you that `surface` is not a valid index in `colors[surface]`. What you actually have there is `colors[(0,1,3,2)]` (for example). What you want is the index of the surface, not the surface itself.

Comment: Additional note: The `glVertex3fv` method always uses the **current state** when submitting vertices. If you call `glColor3fv` after `glVertex3fv` it will color the next vertex you draw, not the current one.

Comment: Thank you i have understand my error. Now i see. Thanks too for explenations.

Answer (score 0):

[`glColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml) sets the current color attribute. [`glVertex`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml) specify a vertex and associates the current color, normal, texture coordinates, and fog coordinate attributes to the vertex.
Hence, the color attribute has to be set before the vertex coordinate is specified:

```py
glBegin(GL_QUADS)
for surface in surfaces:
    for vertex in surface:
        glColor3fv(colors[surface])
        glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])
glEnd()
```

The attributes such as the color are global states and affect all of the following vertices. If the color is changed, it will remain until it is changed again. Therefore, you need to specify the color before drawing the geometry. Otherwise the last set color is used:

```py
glColor3f(1, 1, 1)

glBegin(GL_LINES)
for edge in edges:
    for vertex in edge:
        glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])
glEnd()
```